# вопрос по дебаггеру code blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

Здравствуйте.
Объясню свой вопрос на примере:)

При следующем коде:

```
struct database {
    int rowId;
    int name;
    float surname;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct database worker;
    worker.rowId = 1;
    worker.name = 2;
    worker.surname = 0.5;
    return 1;
}
```

В дебаггере в watches видна вся структура переменной worker со значениями.
[image: code blocks watches]

А при таком коде:

```
struct database {
    int rowId;
    int name;
    float surname;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct database* worker;
    worker = (struct database*)malloc(sizeof(struct database));
    worker->rowId = 1;
    worker->name = 2;
    worker->surname = 0.5;
    return 1;
}
```

Виден только адрес, куда ссылается указатель.
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Вопрос: как посмотреть структуру переменной во 2-м случае? И еще вопросик: можно ли сделать, чтобы в watches выводился так же и тип переменной, а не только значение?

Answer (score 3):

Через э... одно место :)

1) Правой мышой на переменной `worker`, там - "Watch 'worker'"

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

2) В окне Watches снова правой мышой, "Dereference worker"

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

3) И раскрыть плюсик:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: У меня окно watches выглядит иначе. Ни одна переменная не отображается. Не понимаю, как добавить переменную в окно. При нажатии ПКМ по переменной в программе в списке команд нет watch. Что делать? ([![У меня окно watches выглядит иначе](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCvJn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCvJn.png)): https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCvJn.png

Comment: Или можно руками вписать `*worker` в окно Watches.